# My fft2 function not work with me

Tags: matlab

I faced a problem when I convert these two statements from build in to my own function:

```
gaus=gauss/sum(gauss(:));
 BeforeAbs=fft2(gaus,size(im,1),size(im,2));
```

And it gave me [Attempted to access X(2); index out of bounds because numel(X)=1]

```
 %--------Start convert from build in to my own function of Fourier transformation of 1 D
            gaus=gauss/sum(gauss(:));

            for u=1:(gaus)
            summ=0;
            for x=1:1
            w2=(-1*(sqrt(-1)))*2*pi*((u*x)/(gaus+1))
            summ=summ+(gaus(x)*exp(w2)); 
            end
            PQ2(u)=summ;
            end% 


       X=size(im,1);
       for u=1:(X)
            summ=0;
          for x=1:1
               w3=(-1*(sqrt(-1)))*2*pi*((u*x)/(X+1))
               summ=summ+(X(x)*exp(w3)); 
          end
            PQ3(u)=summ;
       end


     BeforeAbs=[PQ2 PQ3];
```

Can anyone tell me why this error appears with me?

Comment: Please reduce this to the **minimum** code that causes the problem.

Comment: OK, See updated version and thank you

Comment: It's not clear how that first code snippet relates to the second code snippet...

Comment: it is the same but reduce as you required.

Comment: No, I mean the relationship between the first two lines above (starting `guas=guass...`) and then the rest of the code above (starting `%-------`).

Comment: I don't know that this problem is clearly described. Could you add a bit more to it, or at least bridge the two parts together?

Comment: The first part is done by build-in fuction in MATLAB, the second part is MY OWN DFT fuction (manual implementation) .The previous version have the full implementation of the above two lines

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the statement

```
X=size(im,1);
```

returns the size of the variable `im` along its first dimension. That would return a scalar value.  However, you have a `for` loop:

```
for x=1:2
  ...
  summ=summ+(X(x)*exp(w3)); 
end
```

that iterates over the values `x = 1` and `x = 2`.  When you try to evaluate `X(x)` when `x = 2`, you get the error because `X` has only one element.

Basically, you are doing something equivalent to this:

```
X = 5
X(2)
```

Also, your for-loop for `u`:

```
for u=0:(X-1)
```

starts from `u = 0`, but later you try to set

```
PQ3(u)=summ;
```

However, array indexing in MATLAB is *1-based*, so `PQ3(0)` would result in an error. You should start indexing from 1: `PQ3(1) = summ`.

Comment: Ok, what can I do to solve it ? I tried to make the loop statred and end by 1 and give me the same problem

Comment: See my additional answer above.

Comment: also started u by 1 also gave me Attempted to access X(2); index out of bounds because numel(X)=1.

Comment: You have to fix both issues, not one or the other. The top part of my answer already addressed the solution for "Attempted to access X(2); index out of bounds because numel(X)=1".

Comment: I fixed both issues and updated the code for what I did. But now other problem show  me :Undefined function or variable "PQ2". Do u mind this problem related to change in the indexing or what?

Comment: I am not sure if you are ready to write your own FFT function before mastering the basic concepts of MATLAB.  Please skim through the [MATLAB Getting Started Guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf), especially the sections about *arrays* and *flow control*.